# Logging into Wordpress via PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I'm currently seeking a solution to logging into Wordpress using PHP/Javascript, I have found examples using cURL but none of them seem to be working for me as of right now (and many of the cURL examples are dated 2009 and earlier). I was wondering if anyone had an idea of how to log onto Wordpress using PHP, perhaps with an updated cURL example? I am using Wordpress version 3.2.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? there is XMLRPC access as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears this question has not been answered yet (for 9 months), I'll state my solution.

For anyone particularly interested in WordPress's brute-forced login protocol without the hassle of `XMLRPC access`:

```
<?php
    require_once('path/to/wp-blog-header.php');
    wp_set_current_user($ID, $user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($ID);
    do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
?>
```

**Caveat**: `$user_login` is not of particular importance - it is used for setting up the session authentication cookie. It is advised that this be randomized for unique values.